# Windows Azure VDI Role

Tags: azure

I have just setup Windows Server 2012 using Windows Azure and I am attempting to install the VDI role so that I can use the server to deploy virtual desktops to other users on the network, however the installation of the role never completes and I receive the following error “Hardware-assisted virtualisation is not present on this server”. Now is this due to the fact that the processor itself doesn't support this or is it literally impossible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course!
You cannot virtualize what is already virtualized! Main principle in virtualization.

That is on one side. On the other side, legally, by the Windows Server License, you are not allowed to deploy and use RDS in any public cloud environment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply :) I honestly hadn't even considered the legality of the issue..but now I know..